# Publishing ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application with Mysql Database

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-4, connection-string, web-deployment

I have successfully created a ASP.NET MVC 4 Web application and now I want to deploy it on a test environment. The target server is not an Azure server, but it is a Windows Server 2008 R2 Server with IIS installed in it. 
Now I have published my solution using Visual Studio 2013 Professional, everything works fine excepts the Database. It's a **Mysql** Database that works perfectly with **Entity Framework 5** (I have added the Mysql provider, **mysql.data.entity.dll** , **mysql.data.dll** on my web project and all the configuration to make it run locally). Once I publish the project, it is deployed on IIS but it doesn't retrieve data from my Mysql Database. I want to notice also that in the Publish wizard, although I specified the connection string, it says that

> there is no Database detected

It should display the name of my context instead of that. Would you please help me know why the publishing wizard doesn't recognize my Mysql Database? thank you for your help !

Comment: Where is the test environment database that it's trying to access? Is it running on the server or is it a database file in the project? Can I see your connection string? Can you access the MySQL database using a database management tool?

Comment: Yes ! The database works fine with the project and I am manipulating it for various CRUD operations in my application. the location of the Database is in the Server itself, in wich I will publish my application, it is deployed in a wamp server and I can have access to it from the application and from other management tools. the only problem is publishing the application.

Comment: you do the database manually for mysql, try and automate these things and its more hassle than its worth

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use `Asp.net MVC` with `MySql` using Entity Framework code first, like the one explained here http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/aspnet-identity-using-mysql-storage-with-an-entityframework-mysql-provider ... Here a couple the things I notice:

- The generated migration contains the schema **`dbo.`** that won't work on `MySql` so I went to the migration file and remove all schema references. (there are better solutions, like configuration/setup wise)
- The unique key length problem, such as UserName (defined in the asp.net Identity) has a maximum length of 256 and that is over the limitations of mysql unique field, so I changed the length to 128. that solved this error

> Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

- I did have some troubles using the publishing wizard, since didn't show me any of my MySql Drivers to test my connection to my db, so I just change the Connection string in the config file and apply my migration changes to the new/testing DB from the Package Manager Console `> Update-Database` (this could be your temporary solution until you find a automatized solution)